# How to specify dependencies when writing a package?

Tags: r, roxygen2

I am trying to write a package that has some dependencies. I am able to load the dependencies manually using `library()`, but I would like them to be loaded automatically together with my package.
I thought the attribute `Imports` on the `DESCRIPTION` file could to the job, but it is not working for me.

So I am starting from scratch with a completely new session:

```
sessionInfo()

R version 3.3.0 (2016-05-03)
Platform: x86_64-apple-darwin13.4.0 (64-bit)
Running under: OS X 10.11.4 (El Capitan)

locale:
[1] en_US.UTF-8/en_US.UTF-8/en_US.UTF-8/C/en_US.UTF-8/en_US.UTF-8

attached base packages:
[1] stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  methods   base     

loaded via a namespace (and not attached):
[1] tools_3.3.0
```

Then I load my package that imports

```
Imports:
 dplyr,
 zipcode,
 readxl,
 mosaic
```

In fact looking again to my session, the dependencies I specified for `mypackage_0.1.0` are loaded correctly:

```
attached base packages:
[1] stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  methods   base     

other attached packages:
[1] mypackage_0.1.0

loaded via a namespace (and not attached):
 [1] Rcpp_0.12.4        nloptr_1.0.4       plyr_1.8.3         tools_3.3.0        mosaic_0.13.0      testthat_1.0.2     digest_0.6.9      
 [8] lme4_1.1-12        zipcode_1.0        memoise_1.0.0      gtable_0.2.0       nlme_3.1-127       lattice_0.20-33    mgcv_1.8-12       
[15] Matrix_1.2-6       DBI_0.4-1          parallel_3.3.0     SparseM_1.7        ggdendro_0.1-20    gridExtra_2.2.1    withr_1.0.1       
[22] dplyr_0.4.3        stringr_1.0.0      roxygen2_5.0.1     MatrixModels_0.4-1 devtools_1.11.1    grid_3.3.0         nnet_7.3-12       
[29] R6_2.1.2           readxl_0.1.1       mosaicData_0.13.0  minqa_1.2.4        reshape2_1.4.1     ggplot2_2.1.0      car_2.1-2         
[36] magrittr_1.5       scales_0.4.0       splines_3.3.0      MASS_7.3-45        assertthat_0.1     pbkrtest_0.4-6     colorspace_1.2-6  
[43] quantreg_5.21      stringi_1.0-1      munsell_0.4.3      crayon_1.3.1
```

However, whenever I write a function nesting other functions from any of the "loaded via namespace" packages, I get an error. For instance:

```
f  <- function(x) {tbl_df(x)}    
> f(cars)
Error in f(cars) : could not find function "tbl_df"
```

I thought the problem was that functions from dependencies could only be used inside other functions of the package I am writing. However, when I defined `f()` as a new function of my package, I got the same error.

I have been suggested to double check that the NAMESPACE file is saved and reloaded.

This is my NAMESPACE file, with the `f()` function.

```
# Generated by roxygen2: do not edit by hand

export(chain_spreadsheet)
export(f)
export(mapping)
export(stalary)
```

However, even after regenerating the documentation and reloading the package, I still have the same issue.

Comment: Have you updated your NAMESPACE file as well?

Comment: Sorry, I double checked. Yes, I updated the NAMESPACE. Still not working.

Comment: Are you referring to the function you are showing or within your package?  Once you updated the NAMESPACE you need to rebuild/reinstall the package and it should work.  You should probably add to NAMESPACE to the question if this is still a problem.

Comment: @cdeterman Thanks, I have added the NAMESPACE file.

Comment: The NAMESPACE should include `import` statements for the dependencies.  In your case `import(dplyr)` I believe is what you are searching for.

Comment: @cdeterman thanks, it worked. I still don't get why roxygen says "do not edit by hand" if even such a basic operation actually needs to be programmed by hand tho. Any ideas?

Answer (score 2):

You need to have the `import` statements in the NAMESPACE file as well.  In order to have this done with `roxygen2` automatically you need to use the `@import` method.

For example, in any .R file

foo.R

```
#' @import dplyr

# my other code
...
```

Now when you rebuild with `roxygen2` the NAMESPACE will be updated automatically.  This is why it states "do not edit by hand" because `roxygen2` is supposed to take care of all of this.  You just need to use the necessary features.

Comment: I apologize,it partially works, but I have not idea why it cannot find the function `readxl::excel_sheehts`. The package `readxl` is within the `loeaded via namespace` libraries when I call `sessionInfo()` but apparently R does not see it. However, I have another function based on `dplyr` which is loaded the way you said and it is working just fine.

Comment: @Dambo is `excel_sheehts` a typo?  Make sure you have the `@import readxl` and that the NAMESPACE does have both after rebuilding.

Comment: Sorry, that was I typo. And yes, it has both, and I can see both of them running `sessionInfo()` (but within the "loaded via namespace", not within the "attached"). And by the way, I still don't get exactly what's the purpose of importing the libraries in the description file, if then I am forced to use `@import` for each single function. I'll create a new package later with only 1 function using both `dplyr` and `readxl` to provide a more solid replication of the issue. Thanks.